# how do i set the environment variable correct

Tags: docker-compose

Im trying to setup email2pfd from this github entry https://github.com/rob-luke/emails-html-to-pdf with docker/portainer but I cant get the WKHTMLTOPDF_OPTIONS correct.

If I use the line from the prebuilt image,
WKHTMLTOPDF_OPTIONS: {"load-media-error-handling":"ignore"}
,it says, that it has to be a string, number , boolean or null and if i try to make it a string by placing quotation marks I get this error: There is an error in the yaml syntax: YAMLSyntaxError: All collection items must start at the same column

Edit: Ok, so this is what I enter in the yml file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  email2pdf:

    image: ghcr.io/rob-luke/emails-html-to-pdf:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: email2pdf
    environment:

      - IMAP_URL=imap.gmx.net
      - IMAP_USERNAME=example.gmx.net
      - IMAP_PASSWORD=12345
      - IMAP_FOLDER=Inbox
      - SMTP_URL=mail.gmx.net
      - MAIL_SENDER=Example.gmx.net
      - MAIL_DESTINATION=Example.gmx.net
      - INTER_RUN_INTERVAL=60
      - HOSTS= 127.0.0.1 tracking.paypal.com
      - WKHTMLTOPDF_OPTIONS='{"enable-local-file-access":"true"}'
```

and this is the log I get:

```
Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file.
Running emails-html-to-pdf
Starting mail processing run
No attachments in: Sicherheitswarnung für 
example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/main.py", line 257, in <module>
PDF: Sicherheitswarnung-für-example.pdf
PDF: Sicherheitswarnung-für-example.pdf
    process_mail(
  File "/app/main.py", line 127, in process_mail
    options = json.loads(pdfkit_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in 
loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in 
decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in 
raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from 
None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 
(char 0)
```

Comment: I used the `docker-compose.yml` example that is given in the `README` and worked perfectly. Perhaps you're using an old version of `docker compose`?

Comment: Can you describe how exactly you did it? Im pretty new to docker and everything and using portainer to make it a little bit easier for me. Did you also use portainer or how do i get to this stage where I can put my environment variables without using portainer

Comment: I saved the code at [this section](https://github.com/rob-luke/emails-html-to-pdf#1-use-prebuilt-image) into `docker-compose.yml`, and ran `docker compose`. I never used portainer so maybe I'm wrong, but it doesn't seem easier to me.

Comment: Hmm I tried using your method, but i still get: services.email2pdf.environment.WKHTMLTOPDF_OPTIONS must be a string, number, boolean or null

Comment: You might be using an old `docker compose`. But this should work also with an old one: `- WKHTMLTOPDF_OPTIONS='{"load-media-error-handling":"ignore"}'` (with single quotes around the value). Also make sure that you either use the list syntax (`- KEY=VALUE`) or the map syntax (`KEY: VALUE`)

Comment: okay, I dont know if this is better or not but if Im doing it how you said it I get this error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). But in line 0 there is only the version right? so why does it expect a value?

Comment: I think you should post it, it's too hard to guess what you have now.

Comment: I edited the original post, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes it look like you had an issue with the syntax of the `docker-compose.yml` file - also the tag suggests that.

After you posted some output, it's clear that your `docker compose` execution works just fine, the container is executed. It's just what's running *in* the container that has an issue with the configuration.

The author's `README` says:

> `WKHTMLTOPDF_OPTIONS`: Python dict (json) representation of
> wkhtmltopdf_options that can be passed to the used pdfkit library

So, as long as the container receives a correct json in that variable, it should work. If it doesn't, you should open a ticket on [emails-html-to-pdf](https://github.com/rob-luke/emails-html-to-pdf).

If I have this (notice that I removed the single quotes!):

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  email2pdf:

    image: ghcr.io/rob-luke/emails-html-to-pdf:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: email2pdf
    environment:

      - IMAP_URL=imap.gmx.net
      - IMAP_USERNAME=example.gmx.net
      - IMAP_PASSWORD=12345
      - IMAP_FOLDER=Inbox
      - SMTP_URL=mail.gmx.net
      - MAIL_SENDER=Example.gmx.net
      - MAIL_DESTINATION=Example.gmx.net
      - INTER_RUN_INTERVAL=60
      - HOSTS=127.0.0.1 tracking.paypal.com
      - WKHTMLTOPDF_OPTIONS={"enable-local-file-access":"true"}
```

and check what the container gets:

```
$ docker compose run --rm --entrypoint='' email2pdf bash
root@a735337855d0:/app# echo ${WKHTMLTOPDF_OPTIONS}
{"enable-local-file-access":"true"}
```

the result is just as expected. Check if you get the same. In that case, you'll need to ask the author.

(I'm running docker-compose 2.16.0 and Docker 23.0.1)

If you get an actual syntax error *from `docker compose`* when you remove the single quotes around the value of `WKHTMLTOPDF_OPTIONS`, then I would say you need to upgrade `docker compose`.

PS. Also notice that in your post, the value of variable `HOSTS` starts with a space. I don't think it's causing the issue you're experiencing, but you should remove it.